# jquery i+1 show/hide

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

How could i show/hide elements on click when it can has various styles starting from one. I need the first sub-item to be clicked - to show 1st item and etc.

Code goes something like this:

```
$('sub-item-' + (i + 1)).click ->
  $('item-' + (i + 1)).show()
  #coffeescript

<div class="item-1">1</div>
<div class="item-2">2</div>
<div class="item-3">3</div>
<div class="item-4">4</div>
etc..

<a href="#" class="sub-item-1">Click 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Click 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub-item-3">Click 3</a>
<a href="#" class="sub-item-4">Click 4</a>
etc..
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your *specific* example, you can use an [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), then parse the class name on the actual element that was clicked. But I wouldn't do that, it's fragile.  (For instance, suppose you added a second class to your `class` attribute? That would complicate the parsing, and if you put it before the `sub-item-*` class, would mess up the selector.) Instead I'd probably either use the position of the item in its container (if you can), or change the markup to use a [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute instead.

Here's an example that assumes your items are the only thing in their container:

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/itukal/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/itukal/1/edit)

```
<!-- (The 'items' are unchanged) -->    

<div><!-- the container, this div is just an example -->
    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Click 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Click 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Click 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Click 4</a>
</div>
```

You can then use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) to find out which div was clicked:

```
$(".sub-item").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.index() + 1;
    $(".item-" + index).show(); // Or toggle, whatever
    return false;
});
```

(You need the `+ 1` because `index` is zero-based.)

But if they're not the only thing in the container, you can use a `data-*` attribute:

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/itukal/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/itukal/2/edit)

```
<!-- (The 'items' are unchanged) -->    

<div><!-- the container, this div is just an example -->
    <a href="#" class="sub-item" data-index="1">Click 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-item" data-index="2">Click 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-item" data-index="3">Click 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-item" data-index="4">Click 4</a>
</div>
```

...which makes it really easy:

```
$(".sub-item").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.attr("data-index");
    $(".item-" + index).show(); // Or toggle, etc.
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest (in 'plain' jQuery):

```
$('div[id^="item-"]').click(
    function(){
        $('a.' + this.id).toggle();
    });
```

References:

- [attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector to select all the anchor tags that start with a specific class name

```
$('a[class^="sub-item-"]')
```

Try this

```
$('a[class^="sub-item-"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $parts = this.className.split('-');

    var $class  = $parts[1] + '-' + $parts[2];

    $('div').hide();

    $('.' + $class).show();
})​
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/aBrsZ/2/)**